# UIActionSheet Title Multiline

Tags: ios, uiactionsheet

Very simply I'd like to have the title of the UI Action Sheet be two lines.

See example below. I'd like to make it:

(line1) Action

(line2) Sheet Demo

Still centered and everything just with a carriage return

[image]

Comment: Did you try putting a `\n` in your title?

Comment: you need to use **\r** because it's NSString * and it's new line is \r (carrage-return)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so because it `takes NSString *` you need to use `\r`

```
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"First Line\rSecond Line", nil)
                                                         delegate:self
                                                cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"_CANCEL", nil)
                                           destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"_USE_SYSTEM_LANGUAGE", nil), NSLocalizedString(@"_ENGLISH", nil), NSLocalizedString(@"_ARABIC", nil), nil];
```

it is copy&paste I use `NSLocalizedString` but you ncat use `NSString`

[image: See picture:]

Comment: Get rid of the space on either side of the `\r`. BTW - `\n` works too.

Comment: @rmaddy I had `\n` buggy under iOS 8 yesterday and `\r` fixed my problem.