# Xamarin UIActionSheet/UIAlertController multiline text

Tags: xamarin.ios

I want to do the same thing as [26408571](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26408571/uiactionsheet-title-multiline) but in Xamarin
 `var alertLabel = UILabel.AppearanceWhenContainedIn(typeof(UIAlertController)` don't give me any Lines or LinesNumber method on the returned UILabelApparence.

How can I achieve the same result with Xamarin?

Answer (score 0):

`UILabelAppearance` doesn't provide property like `Lines` or `LinesNumber`.

What do you want ?

To implement multiline text with UIAlertViewController, just refer to the link , add `\r` in the text string.

```
UIAlertController alert = UIAlertController.Create("Line1\rLine2", "message", UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
this.PresentViewController(alert, false, null);
```

Comment: I want it on the UIAlertAction, not on the UIAlertController Title or Message. You can't use \r or \n to break the line in the UIAlertAction.

Comment: I'm afraid it is not possible, since you have to access the Label in UIAlertAction,however it is not recommended to retrieve views from its subviews. God knows when apple will change the source code.